# My score list is not getting updated. Python (Tic Tac Toe)

Tags: python-2.7, list

Here is what happens.
mc_move
creates scores list and gives it to mc_update_score as an argument.

mc_update_score does all the calculations and updates the list (i checked it by print at the end of mc_update_score function.
But, on the next iteration in mc_move the  scores list is set to initial value - all zeros. Though it is supposed to be the list with values from mc_update_score.
What do i miss here?

```
def mc_update_scores(scores, board, player):

    print "scores at the begining of the function is"
    print scores
    for i in empty_list_score:
       # iterate through all the squares of the board
        col = i[1]
        row = i[0]
        if board.check_win() == provided.DRAW:
            scores[row][col] += 0
            #print score[row][col]
        elif board.check_win() == provided.PLAYERX:
            if board.square(row,col) == provided.PLAYERX:
                scores[row][col] += SCORE_CURRENT
            elif board.square(row,col) == provided.PLAYERO: 
                scores[row][col] -= SCORE_OTHER
            else:
                scores[row][col] += 0        
       # print score[row][col]


        elif board.check_win() == provided.PLAYERO:
            if board.square(row,col) == provided.PLAYERO:
                scores[row][col] += SCORE_CURRENT
            elif board.square(row,col) == provided.PLAYERX: 
                scores[row][col] -= SCORE_OTHER
            else:
                scores[row][col] += 0
    print
    print "Scores at the end"
    print scores 



def mc_move(board, player, trials):

    global empty_list_score

    empty_list_score =board.get_empty_squares()

    scores = [[0  for col in range(board.get_dim())]for row in range(board.get_dim())] # create score board
    # Here we create the scores list just once at function call and from here on
    # it only gets updated. Like each element is getting changed by +1 or - 1.
    # i do not see any spot where the entire list is being created again or 
    #emptied = e.g. is set to all zeros.
    num = 0


    while num < trials:
        board_c = board.clone() # create new board for every iteration
        mc_trial(board_c, player) # play a full game for every iteration
        mc_update_scores(scores, board_c, player)  # update score for every 
           #iteration after the game is played. 

        num +=1
```

Comment: You are doing `+=0` which increments by zero. Did you mean to write `+=1`?

Comment: There are different cases. As you can see some of the do +1, some -1 and some leave as is +0. probably makes no sense ) but it does not influence the misbehaviour of the list as far as i can see.

Comment: Does `mc_trial` call `mc_move` at some point? From what I see, there's no obvious reason for `scores` to get reset to all zeros, but we don't have all the code (and so we can't run your code to debug it ourselves). Recursion would be one reason to see more zero scores. Can you make a [mcve] perhaps?

Comment: @Blckknght   Here is the link for full executable code [link](http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user42_u0NhhhdalB_10.py) The mc_trial does not return anything. All it does is updates the board, which is then used in the next step in mc_move. At least it is supposed to)

Comment: From looking at that code, the only thing I see is that `NTRIALS` is `1`, so your `while` loop may only run a single time. That code is still not "complete" since I can't download it and run it on my own system (it relies on various other modules that I don't know anything about), so I'm still just guessing at what's going on.